# .htaccess rewirte all to https expects one query_string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, query-string

Simple question. I just want to rewrite everything to https besides the url with the query string `feed=rss2&cat=25`. For my point of view the following code should work. Any ideas?

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /news/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^feed=rss2&cat=25$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/news/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is this the only rule or you have more rules? Better you post your complete .htaccess here

Comment: That is the only rule I'll created

Comment: ok what is the exact URL are you entering in browser to test this and where is this htaccess located?

Comment: The url is domain.com/news/?feed=rss2&cat=25 and the .htaccess is located in htdocs/news/

Comment: @user1747547 and it does not redirect to HTTPS or what happens when you test it?

Comment: everything will be redirected to HTTPS, also the url with the query_string feed=rss2&cat=2. the url with this query_string feed=rss2&cat=2 should NOT be redirected to HTTPS

Comment: Change `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^feed=rss2&cat=25$` to `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^feed=rss2&cat=25|cat=25&feed=rss2$ [NC]` to make sure it will catch the query string no matter how it is typed and see if that changes anything for you. Also keep in mind that your system could also be forcing it to go to HTTPS so you will have to ensure that is not the case as that is out of `.htaccess` hands.

Comment: So you're seeing `http://domain.com/news/?feed=rss2&cat=25` being redirected to `https://domain.com/news/?feed=rss2&cat=25` in your browser? What happens when you rename this .htacess and retest?

Comment: Ill try and let you know

Comment: It seems that the news application ifselfs redirect to HTTPS. so there is no .htaccess problem. Thanks guys.